# Flutter widget panel with header and body?

Tags: flutter

Which Flutter widget for Panel with header and body?

```
-------------------
header
-------------------
body
-------------------
```

For example,

```
  --------------------------
  |   Login                |
  |-------------------------
  |   Username:________    |
  |                        |
  |   Password:________    |
  |                        |  
  |   Sign UP              |
  |   Reset Password       |
  |------------------------|
```

Comment: if expandable >> ExpansionTile or just `Column` will be enough

Comment: Is there a Material design for header/body? Column does not have it.  thanks.

Comment: actually you need to style the widget where `Theme.of(context).textTheme` is might what are you looking for.

Answer (score 0):

you can use Card Setting Package :

```
dependencies:
  card_settings: ^3.5.0
```

Example:

```
import 'package:card_settings/card_settings.dart';

String title = "Spheria";
  String author = "Cody Leet";
  String url = "http://www.codyleet.com/spheria";

  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      body: Form(
        key: _formKey,
        child: CardSettings(
          children: <CardSettingsSection>[
            CardSettingsSection(
              header: CardSettingsHeader(
                label: 'Favorite Book',
              ),
              children: <CardSettingsWidget>[
                CardSettingsText(
                  label: 'Title',
                  initialValue: title,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value == null || value.isEmpty) return 'Title is required.';
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) => title = value,
                ),
                CardSettingsText(
                  label: 'URL',
                  initialValue: url,
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (!value.startsWith('http:')) return 'Must be a valid website.';
                  },
                  onSaved: (value) => url = value,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```